# Why this Bash script runs on a machine but fails on another?

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a program which needs to access the I/O ports of my motherboard so it needs root permission. I wanted to run this program at system start up but since the Ubuntu system start up cannot run applications with root permission I wrote these two simple files:

askpass.sh

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS="/var/www/Bash/mits/getpass.sh"; 
sudo -A -E /home/mits/QtProjects/HandST/HandST // this is the address of my application
```

getpass.sh

```
echo 'P54_99**'    //this is my password
```

as it is appear in the askpass.sh file, I used **SUDO_ASKPASS** as stated in sudo manual to run my application with sudo password located in anther file.

when I call askpass.sh in my laptop it works fine and the applications will start, but when I run this script in my PC server located in my office it gives the following error.(I use remote access to reach to my server )

```
./askpass.sh
**./askpass.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found**
sudo: unable to run /var/www/Bash/mits/getpass.sh: Exec format error
Sorry, try again.
sudo: unable to run /var/www/Bash/mits/getpass.sh: Exec format error
Sorry, try again.
sudo: unable to run /var/www/Bash/mits/getpass.sh: Exec format error
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

what is this $'\r' variable (I don't have anything like that in my code ! it seems like \n at the end of the files or something like that !!!) !! these two files are exactly the same with my laptop files only the path and the password is changed for the server but why it fails to run on my server ? I am sure the password is modified to be the server password and I tested that many times. but I don't know why it gives error on the password too :(

I also tried to put my application path in rc.local which is run with root permission but it also failed.

I only want to try this one as a solution so I would be happy to propose your solution for this type of start up handling.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm able to replicate the error if I add a line starting with `$'\r'` into `askpass.sh`. Are you sure you're running the same script?

Comment: yes, I'm sure about it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have embedded windows line endings (`\r\n`) in your shell script, you can run the command `dos2unix` on the file and that should fix it. If you don't have `dos2unix` you can use `tr` and something like,

```
tr -d '\r' < askpass.sh > out.sh
```

Then

```
mv out.sh askpass.sh
```

Comment: The $\r problem is solved. but I still face the wrong password problem ! I am sure my password is "P54_99**" but why it tells me its wrong should I change echo command to something else ?

Comment: @PsP run the above on `/var/www/Bash/mits/getpass.sh` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this as the first line of Your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Maybe you have on the other machine set different shell. Try check it by running

```
env | grep SHELL
```